# Stringer separating from deck stairs

Tags: deck, stairs

I’ve got a not quite 2 yr old deck installed by our builder. We have a problem with the stringers pulling away from the treads and risers. We first started noticing it last year, so I added some 3.5” deck screws to each board to try to secure them, but they’re pulling out as well. This is happening to almost all the treads and risers on both sides.

Just wondering at this point what the best course is? Is this repairable, or do I need to look at replacing the stairs?

[image: stringer separating]

[image: back side]

Comment: Also, can you take a picture of the underside of the steps?

Comment: Added picture of the back side

Answer (score 5):

The issue you are running into now is that end grains are poor for holding power. I would make 2x4 blocks 4” long and secure it in the corners underneath each side of the steps. The grain should run front to back, screw it into the stringer, then pull the stairs tight together, then screw the treads into the block; this will lock it into place.

Answer (score 2):

Add metal angle connectors to connect the tread to the stringer. Use the Simpson Strong-Tie TA Stairway Tread Angle.
 https://www.strongtie.com/deckconnectors_decks/ta_angle/p/ta

[image: Simpson TA]